# Show units when doing dstat -n

Tags: linux, ubuntu, network-monitoring

Question is simple as, when i do dstat -n i get what I assume to be a unit in bytes? But i would like a way to force the units into Mb/s or for it to simply tell me the unit it is displaying. Is there any way i can do this, or is there a similar tool to dstat which will give me this option. I am only talking about network here, i am not concerned about  my disk usage/memmory usage etc.

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of my dstat -n seems to be showing the Meg or K of my net traffic. This is with version 0.7.2 on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS host.

```
----total-cpu-usage---- -dsk/total- -net/total- ---paging-- ---system--
usr sys idl wai hiq siq| read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw 
  4   3  92   1   0   0|  93k  119k|   0     0 |   0     0 |3023  4760 
 15   2  82   0   0   1|   0     0 |  12M  251k|   0     0 |  13k   15k
 17   4  80   0   0   0|   0     0 |  12M  247k|   0     0 |  13k   15k
 16   3  79   1   0   1|   0   108k|  12M  248k|   0     0 |  14k   15k
```

Is it possible the color output of dstat is making it tricky to read?

```
s@purgatory:~$ dstat -n --nocolor
-net/total-
 recv  send
  0     0 
 12M  250k
 12M  247k
```